# Javascript/jQuery working perfectly in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been using some code recently that allows people to pay with Paypal Express Checkout when they are using our site in GBP currency, but I don't want the option there when they are using Euro's, Dollars, or any other currency.

In my Custom CSS I've used

```
.paypalbutton {display: none !important;}
```

Then in my Javascript/Jquery I've used

```
window.setInterval(function(){
if (jQuery(".currency-selector:contains('GBP')").length) {
    jQuery(".paypalbutton").attr('style', 'display: inline-block !important');
 } 1000});
```

The reason I've done it this way is because the Paypal button is loaded in dynamically with PHP. And for some reason .on and .live don't seem to work.

Now this works perfectly in Google Chrome, which is what I've been testing in. But for some reason this wont work in Firefox (haven't tested other browsers yet). So my question is, Why wont it work in Firefox?

Thanks for any help.

Some more info:

The code doesn't seem to be having any problems in firefox when typed into the console, its just that the paypal button that should be showing when on 'GBP' is not showing in firefox but does in chrome.

Chrome has:

```
.paypalbutton {display: inline-block !important}
<strike>.paypalbutton {display: none !important}</strike>
```

Firefox has:

```
.paypalbutton {display: none !important}
<strike>.paypalbutton {display: inline-block !important}</strike>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Does the timer not fire? Does it fire but not find the element? Does it fire and find the element but not change the `style` attribute? The first step here is debugging, using the powerful debugger built into Firefox.

Comment: What is the `.currency-selector` element?

Comment: What is jQuery(".currency-selector:contains('GBP')").length returning?

Comment: As Sumon Sarker points out, that code is missing a comma before the `1000`, which means it wouldn't work in Chrome, either.

Comment: Rather than using `setInteval` why not do a delegated on load of the `.currency-selector` element, that way the code will fire once the element is loaded rather than every second

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The currency-selector element is a dropdown with each currency.

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma that statement is returning 1 in both browsers

Comment: @DM98: By "drop-down," what do you mean? `select` element?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder .currency-selector is a span within a button. So like <button><span class="currency-selector">GBP</span></button>

Comment: @DM98: Great. How about the missing comma before 1000? (See above.) Is it really missing in your code? (Given that that would make it fail in Chrome as well as Firefox, it seems unlikely.) (Actually, it's worse than that, there's a missing `,` and the 1000 is in the wrong place.)

Comment: With the typo fixed, as far as we can tell, it works: https://jsfiddle.net/ff2L7qnx/ Please either update the question with a [mcve] and address the various questions in the comments above, or delete it. We can't help you with the information supplied so far (other than pointing out typos your web console is telling you above, if they're really in your code).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've just used JS from your fiddle and it works in both Chrome and Firefox! Thanks. Only issue now is a very brief disappear and reappear of the button. If you have time could you please explain why my code wasn't working in Firefox but was in Chrome and what your code did to fix it? Again Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error defining `setInterval` function

**Try like as below :**

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  if(jQuery(".currency-selector:contains('GBP')").length){
    jQuery(".paypalbutton").attr('style', 'display: inline-block !important');
    /*jQuery(".paypalbutton").css({
       'display' : 'inline-block !important'
      });*/
 }
},1000);
```

> **Note :** `Console` your output from both browsers. Check if there is any `Script Error`. Check if Javascript `disabled/not supported` by browser.

Here is the `setInterval` function syntax

```
window.setInterval(myCallbackFunction, DurationInMilliseconds);
```

**Example :**

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(myCallback, 500);
function myCallback() {
  // Your code here
}
```

> More details about [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) function. And [jQuery Browser Support](https://jquery.com/browser-support/)

Comment: This reads like a game of spot-the-difference. Say **what** you changed, and **why**.

Comment: But more importantly: If the code works in Chrome, we know the missing comma is just a typo in the question, not their real code -- because it would be an error in Chrome as well as Firefox if the comma were really missing.

Comment: @SumonSarker

If i'm reading your comment correctly, I've tried using

window.setInterval(function(){
  if(jQuery(".currency-selector:contains('GBP')").length){
    jQuery(".paypalbutton").css({'display' : 'inline-block !important');
 }
},1000); 

This is not working and is giving me the error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

And so is:

var intervalID = window.setInterval(myCallback, 1000);
function myCallback() {
if (jQuery(".currency-selector:contains('GBP')").length) {
    jQuery(".paypalbutton").attr('style', 'display: inline-block !important');
} 1000});

Comment: Opps! i missed `}` . Answer is updated now. Please check @DM98

Comment: @SumonSarker Ah. Thanks! I've now tried : 
window.setInterval(function(){
  if(jQuery(".currency-selector:contains('GBP')").length){
    jQuery(".paypalbutton").css({
       'display' : 'inline-block !important'
      });
 }
},1000);

And it doesn't return any errors, but it also dosen't show the class in Chrome or Firefox. {display: inline-block !important} is nowhere in inspect.

Comment: Try `window.setInterval(function(){
  if(jQuery(".currency-selector:contains('GBP')").length){
    jQuery(".paypalbutton").attr('style', 'display: inline-block !important');
    alert('working!');
 }else{
    alert('Not working');
}
},1000);` @DM98

Comment: Or share your all code with `HTML` here https://pastebin.com/ and give me the link. So, I can check actually what is wrong there. @DM98

Comment: @SumonSarker Thanks for all your help, the JS that T.J. Crowder provided in his fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/ff2L7qnx/) worked. Though i think it was based on your answer. Thanks so much!